# Retrieve user's information from Facebook or Twitter in Django

Tags: python, django, facebook

I have created Django's registration process using `django.contrib.auth` and have also set up user profiles. Now I want to add an option to fetch the profile's information from third-party sites like Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn. I have found `django-socialregistration`, but I don't know how to override the default setup view. What is the best and easy solution for the task?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the basic idea of the setup that I use, although it's only for Facebook:

1. Integrate the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)
2. Bind a JavaScript function which calls [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) to a "login with Facebook" button, request all the permissions that you need for that user
3. In the `function(response)` section of the `FB.login` call, handle the returned response, then do an Ajax POST to a Django view (I use jQuery for this) which takes the response, parses it to retrieve the access token for the user and store it in the user profile object for that user.
4. You can then use this access_token to make Facebook [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) requests on behalf of that user server-side, or if you want, you can actually just use the JavaScript SDK to make all your calls entirely on the client-side with lots of Ajax to interact with the Django backend.

I find this to be a much easier solution than trying to use one of the Django packages, because most of them are out of date.

Comment: Sometimes this type of answers with a general strategy are better than implementation details.